# división entre ceros

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

buenos días estoy realizando un programa en php con MVC resulta que necesito que se visualice la división entre dos tablas y posterior multiplicación para que me arroje un porcentaje de cumplimiento según de la división[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] solo que no logro que se muestre en pantalla ni que realice el calculo

tambien tengo el codigo que estoy utilizando en el controlador que es el siguente
`/*=============================================
EFICACIA MENSUAL
=============================================*/
static public function ctrEficaciaMensual($mes) {
$valor = $_GET["idOperacion"];

```
    $tareas = ModeloTareas::mdlMostrarTareas($valor);
    $nrotareas = 0;

    $mes_prog = "";
    $mes_ejec = "";

    if( $mes == 1){
        $mes_ejec = "ene_prog"; 
        $mes_prog = "ene_ejec";
    }elseif( $mes == 2){
        $mes_ejec = "feb_prog"; 
        $mes_prog = "feb_ejec";
    }elseif( $mes == 3){
        $mes_ejec = "mar_prog"; 
        $mes_prog = "mar_ejec";
    }elseif( $mes == 4){
        $mes_ejec = "abr_prog"; 
        $mes_prog = "abr_ejec";
    }elseif( $mes == 5){
        $mes_ejec = "may_prog"; 
        $mes_prog = "may_ejec";
    }elseif( $mes == 6){
        $mes_ejec = "jun_prog"; 
        $mes_prog = "jun_ejec";
    }elseif( $mes == 7){
        $mes_ejec = "jul_prog"; 
        $mes_prog = "jul_ejec";
    }elseif( $mes == 8){
        $mes_ejec = "ago_prog"; 
        $mes_prog = "ago_ejec";
    }elseif( $mes == 9){
        $mes_ejec = "sep_prog"; 
        $mes_prog = "sep_ejec";
    }elseif( $mes == 10){
        $mes_ejec = "oct_prog"; 
        $mes_prog = "oct_ejec";
    }elseif( $mes == 11){
        $mes_ejec = "nov_prog"; 
        $mes_prog = "nov_ejec";
    }else{
        $mes_ejec = "dic_prog"; 
        $mes_prog = "dic_ejec";
    }

    $suma = 0;
    $eficacia = 0;
    foreach ($tareas as $key => $tarea) {

        echo '<script> console.log("'.$key++.' mes -->  '.$mes_prog.' '.$mes_ejec.'"); </script>';
        if($tarea[$mes_prog] == 0 || $tarea[$mes_ejec] == 0){
            if($eficacia = 0){
                $suma = $suma + 1;
            }else{
                $eficacia = $suma + ($tarea[$mes_ejec]/$tarea[$mes_prog]);
            }
            $nrotareas++;
        } 
        /*if($mes_prog == 0 || $mes_ejec == 0)
             {
                 $eficacia = 0;
             }
             else
             {
                 $eficacia = $mes_ejec/$mes_prog;
             }
        }*/
    
    
    

    return $eficacia;

}
}`
```

Comment: Sabes que la Matemática no permite la división entre ceros?????? Puedes dar una mejor contexto de tu duda???

Comment: la división de los campos de mes programado con mes ejecutado el resultado se tiene que multiplicar por un 100 para tener un porcentaje de eficiencia y de eficacia no todos los memes serán divisiones de cero pero el resultado debe de verse reflejado en donde dice plan operativo anual